# Average data by 3 hours period (calculate by previous and next hour) in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I would like to compute the average of a time-series data by a period of 3 hours (my data include 10 minutes values). However, I would like to compute the average from the previous and the next hour and a half. For example, I need the 0:00 average computed by the data between 22:30 and 1:30.

If I use this:

```
threehour <- aggregate(list(x = df$x, u = df$u), 
                   list(hourofday = cut(df$Datetime, "3 hours")), 
                   mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, with this code, I will have the average at 3:00 (from 0:00 to 3:00).

In conclusion, I need the average centered in 0:00 (avg from 22:30 to 1:30), 3:00 (avg from 1:30 to 4:30), 6:00, 9:00, 12:00, 15:00, 18:00 and 21:00.

Comment: check package zoo, function rollmean

Comment: Group by classes : A=22:30-1:30, B=1:30-4:30, C=..., ..., H. Then compute the average on each group. You can do this manually, or with a factor. If you need to test/analyze the impact of the factors, the technique is called Experimental Design, and you have a specialized package in R called ExperimentalDesign.

Comment: @phiver I can't figure out how to use rollmean...

Comment: @AlainD I new in R, also don't know how to group by classes. My data is very long...

Comment: It is chapter 4 of the official https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html. You'll probably need to read Chapter 2.7 to build your factor. Basically A <- mean(data[22:30 <hourofday <1:30]) **(exact syntax to be adapted)**, and the same for the other 7 cases.